Is it reasonable to split the data and then perform the regression?
There's a store that sells ballpoint pens. I have obtained data on each transaction from this store, including transaction IDs, colors, sell number per transaction, total prices, etc. By dividing the total price by the per transaction number, I calculated the unit price per pen in each transaction. I think that the unit price of each ballpoint pen is related to its color and the number purchased in each transaction. Therefore, I will test this hypothesis using linear regression: Unit Price = Alpha1 x Color + Alpha2 x Number + Beta.
raw data image:

The question is, can I split this data before performing the regression? For example, in the raw sample data, the first transaction sold 2 ballpoint pens, so I would split it into two entries. The split data would be as shown below, with the regression equation remaining the same: Unit Price = Alpha1 x Color + Alpha2 x Number + Beta.
split data image:

My question is: Is this operation OK? What impact might it have and why? Are there any references for this?
I think this operation might be unreasonable, for example, it actually increases the weight of the data for the blue pens. However, my understanding of statistics is insufficient, so I cannot clearly articulate why or how it is unreasonable.

When you "blow up" the data in the way you suggest, your data coming from the same transaction are highly dependent. Take two observations from the same transaction, and you will see that they are equal in price. Or, there is an intra-class correlation of 1, where class means "transaction". There is a formula expressing that in this situation your "effective" number of (independent) observations is actually lower than the observed number:
$$N_{\textrm{effective}} = \frac{N_{\textrm{observed}}} {1+ICC\times (\text{average number}-1)}$$
where "average number" is the average number of ballpoints per transaction. Say your data contain 100 different transactions, and suppose each transaction has the same number of ballpoints, 3, then $N_\textrm{observed}=3\times 100$. However, $N_\textrm{effective}=300 / (1+1\times (3-1)) = 300 / 3 = 100$! This means that if you would apply your regression model to the blown-up data, you actually must use 100 as your "sample size" instead of 300, when e.g. estimating the std. error of the color dummies. This means that you could as well have used you original "transaction" data right from the start, instead of the blown-up "ballpoint" data!
Things would get different if you would also have ballpoint features of each individual ballpoint, influencing the price of an individual ballpoint! That seems not the case for you. But if so, you could use a so called "random effects" models, where each transaction is supposed to have its own random effect on the price.

Today's $\LaTeX$ tip: use \times instead of *; the latter represents convolution of measures, totally different thing.
